# Trying to understand requirejs, shim and dependencies while updating code

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, requirejs, es5-shim

Short version:
I'm updating some old libs to try to get them in AMD/requirejs format for management, but some of them have dependencies on old code.

Main Question:
I'm primarily confused as to what to list in the:

```
define(['what','goes','here'],function('what','needs','to','be','here'){})
```

and what goes in the shim dependencies list when dealing with combinations of AMD and non-AMD tools, and things like jquery-ui and jquery plugins.

ADDITIONAL INFO

The problem:

One of the older libraries depends on .draggable() from (and older version of) jquery-ui, some old version of a jquery plugin called 'onScreen', a spinner modal called spin.js -- all of which are not AMD friendly. (I also implemented an update to an AMD friendly new version of dropzone)
Two of the older libraries also use a modal library called vex which requires a dependency of vex.dialog. The existing site has an old version that is uglified.

I'm trying not to completely revamp this code as the longer term goal would be to remove those dependencies entirely, but I may not have to the time now to figure out what they are doing.

I've tried every combination of define(['list','of','stuff']) I can think of, but some of the libraries like spin (class Spinner), vex/vex.dialog and onScreen still don't always load properly. (sometimes I get one, but then lose another)

Can I define a shim AND include a list of AMD modules in the define? And if so, do I include the AMD list of dependencies in the shim in require.config? What goes where and why?

My libraries:

```
ImageSelector (requires AwsHelper, Utilities and ImageLayout below)
  -- uses jquery (AMD), dropzone (AMD) and an old jquery plugin called jquery.onscreen.js (non-AMD)
  -- depends on vex and vex.dialog (non-AMD)
  -- uses .draggable() from old jquery-ui (non-AMD)
  -- calls a global function 'loadSpinner' which uses spin.js (non-AMD -- see Utilities below)

ImageLayout (requires AwsHelper and Utilities - has attached instance of ImageSelector as a property .selector for methods that work in conjunction with the selector)
  -- uses jquery (AMD)
  -- also utilizes vex/vex.dialog (non-AMD)

Utilities
  -- I'm trying to move the loadSpinner() function that requires spin.js (class Spinner, non-AMD) into this
  -- I've managed thus far to avoid dependencies on things like jquery in this by refactoring code
```

Long version:

I'm trying to update some website code to use require.js for dependency management and to make the code more portable. But I'm running into a number of dependencies on old code that don't appear to be AMD-ready. Where possible, I'm trying to replace these with updated code and/or replace their functionality entirely, but in a number of cases, the code is minified and it's difficult to get a quick handle on what it's doing.
Rather than getting mired in minutia of trying to figure out and either replace or update these things, I read about how 'shim' can be used in some cases to handle these types of non-AMD code, but I'm still unclear on how to configure them.

Here's what I have...  I have three libraries I have updated and one new one I created. One called 'ImageSelector' builds a web-gui to allow uploading files with dropzone. (My reason for updating it is that I converted it from using a local filesystem to using Amazon AWS S3 storage.)  A second one called 'ImageLayout' handles the business logic of creating a product layout of photos selected by the user. (ImageSelector is split into two frames, a left one for uploading and sorting user files into folders, a right one for building the layout. Thus ImageSelector is dependent on ImageLayout)

The third library is one I created just with a number of repeatedly use 'utility' functions used across the website. There is an existing structured-code version of this in global scope with just a list of functions like roundPrecision(), sanitizeFilename(), escapeRegex(), baseName(), etc.  I was going to build this with static methods, but then realized I can customize it if I spawn instances of it instead (e.g. I can change the characters 'sanitized' for different applications with global instance parameters)
The new one is the AwsHelper which is not a problem as it's entirely new code and handles all the interaction with Amazon AWS and S3. It was created in a define() AMD format while the others I have converted to define()/export format.

Anyway, some functions of the ImageLayout can be used independently by the order system, but for the most part, it's used as a dependency of the ImageSelector. AwsHelper is used mostly by ImageSelector but there are two functions in ImageLayout that utilize it. All of the above use the Utilities library.

My guess is something like this in the config (using ImageSelector as an example, but I'm wondering if "jquery" an "dropzone" need to be in there or the function define or both?)

```
shim: {
        "ImageSelector": {
            deps: ["jquery","dropzone","vex","vex.dialog","jquery-ui","jquery.onscreen"]
        }
    }
```

Additional require.js semantic questions:

(I'll post these separately if needed, but they may be short-answer and related)

Is there anything anywhere that shows how require.js searches for files? e.g. I understand about r.js for uglifying, but in some cases I can't track down the original code for these things. Can filenames include .min.js on the end or version numbers and will require.js still find them or should I rename and/or symlink files? e.g. jquery.js vs jquery-1.7.min.js for example.

The spin.js referenced above actually includes a class definition called 'Spinner'. How do I represent that in the config/shim?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I posted that based on my experimenting the last 3 days riddled with failures, expecting more trouble. But apparently, shim was straightforward and having the required libs in more than one place (shim definitions and define([])) wasn't a problem.

I took a blind guess going through the examples on the require.js and came up with this configuration and amazingly it worked first try! (which makes me nervous as this is the first time I've gotten this code to work with no errors since trying to import it to require.js)

Here's what I came up with:

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "/js/lib",
    "paths": {
        "ImageSelector"  : "../awsS3/ImageSelector",
        "ImageLayout"    : "../awsS3/ImageLayout",
        "AwsHelper"      : "../awsS3/AwsHelper",
        "Utilities"      : "../awsS3/Utilities"
    },
    "shim": {
        "jquery.onscreen": {
            "deps": ['jquery'],
            "exports": 'jQuery.fn.onScreen'
        },
        "jquery-ui" : ['jquery'],
        "vex.dialog" : ['jquery','vex'],
        "vex" : ['jquery'],
        "spin" : {
            "exports": "Spinner"
        },
        "aws-sdk" : {
            "exports" : "AWS"
        },
        "Utilities": ["spin"],
        "AwsHelper": ["jquery","aws-sdk"],
        "ImageSelector": {
            "deps" : ["jquery","dropzone","vex","vex.dialog","jquery-ui","jquery.onscreen","ImageLayout","AwsHelper","Utilities"]
        },
        "ImageLayout": {
            "deps" : ["jquery","vex","vex.dialog","Utilities"]
        }
    }
});
```

I also noted that some of the version naming was handled in the paths, thus I just named my libs in the paths and got rid of my "app/" directory reference altogether.